# java.awt.Robot.keyPress for continuous keystrokes

Tags: java, eclipse, keypress, unity-game-engine, awtrobot

So, here's my problem. I have a java program which will send keystroke messages to a game (built in Unity), based on how the user interacts with an android phone. (My java program is a listener for the android interaction over wi-fi) Now, in order to do this, I am using `java.awt.Robot` to send keyPresses to the game window. I have the following code block written in my listener program:

```
if(interacting)
{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(VK_A);
    robot.delay(20); //to simulate the normal keyboard rate
}
```

Now the variable `interacting` will be true as long as the user presses down on the touch screen of the phone, and what I intend to achieve is a continuous chain of keystroke messages being delivered to the game (through the listener). However, this is severely affecting performance, for some reason. I am noticing that the game becomes slow (rapidly dropping frame rates), and even the computer becomes slow, in general. What's going wrong? Should I use a `robot.keyRelease(VK_A)` after each `keyPress`? But my game has a different action mapped to the release of a key, and I do not want rapid key presses and releases; what I really want is to simulate continuous keystrokes, in *exactly* the way it would behave if the user were pressing down the `A` key on their keyboard manually. Please help.

Comment: Huh?  Android does not offer an AWT Robot.

Answer (score 2):

robot object will actually simulate the same keyboard and mouse control pattern as any normal user would. therefore in every case where a key is pressed it should be released.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(10000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.delay(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

this example will open a notepad window.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you press a key with the `Robot` you also need to release it.

Perhaps something along these lines?

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

if(interacting)
{
    robot.keyPress(VK_A);
    robot.delay(20); //to simulate the normal keyboard rate
    robot.keyRelease(VK_A);
    robot.delay(20); //to simulate the normal keyboard rate
}
```